# How to generate a array with points of this curve?

Tags: python, math, geometry

I want to code a program to generate an array with coordinates to follow for drawing a shape   like the white here, given are the blue points. Does anyone know how to do something like that or at least can give me a tip?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use e.g. [`InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation-in-1-d-object-oriented-univariatespline) to interpolate the points. As these spline functions are usually 1D, you could calculate `x` and `y` positions separately, depending on a new variable `t` going from 0 to 1.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

# positions of the given points
px = [1, 4, 3, 2, 5] 
py = [1, 3, 4, 3, 1]
# 5 t-values, at t=0 in point 1, at t=1 reaching point 5
pt = np.linspace(0, 1, len(px))
# sx and sy are functions that interpolate the points at the given t-values 
sx = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(pt, px)
sy = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(pt, py)
# calculate many intermediate values
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 500)
x = sx(t)
y = sy(t)

# show the original points together with the spline
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='black')
ax.axis('off')
plt.scatter(px, py, s=80, color='skyblue')
plt.plot(x, y, color='white')
for i, (xi, yi) in enumerate(zip(px, py), start=1):
    ax.text(xi, yi, f'\n  {i}', ha='left', va='center', size=30, color='yellow')
plt.show()
```

[image: interpolating points]

Comment: I am gonna ahve to do a lot of research on this solution, but it seems right, so I'll accept it already. Thanks!